# Add a cell to a table based on href in another cell using jQuery

Tags: jquery

```
<tr>
 <!--INSERT NEW CELL HERE -->
 <td>
  <a href="test123.html">test</a>
 </td>
```

I need to drop a new cell in that space based on the href test123.html. I tried:

```
jQuery("td[href$='test123.html']").before("<td>new cell</td>");
```

But no dice. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

u missed `a` there since href is the attribute of `<a>` and not `<td>`.

try this

```
jQuery("td a[href$='test123.html']").before("<td>new cell</td>");
  //------^^-----here
```

however this will place the new td before `<a>` , to place it ibefore `<td>` you have to use parent() or closest()..

```
jQuery("a[href$='test123.html']").parent().before("<td>new cell</td>");
//or
jQuery("a[href$='test123.html']").closest("td").before("<td>new cell</td>");
```

[fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/vJU9Y/2/)